# Abnormal build process termination Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-17

I've come across the problem that intellij won't start the java application as it give me an error of abnormal build process termination. Keep in mind that the java application is using JDK 17. Did anyone came across this problem before?

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Starting the intellij and picking the java project.
2. Starting the application

**Expected behaviour**

Application starts after compilation

**Actual behaviour**

*Short error:*

Compiler intrinsic is defined for method [jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.storeStoreFence()V], but the method is not annotated with @IntrinsicCandidate. Method will not be inlined.
Error occurred during initialization of VM

*Logs*

```
Abnormal build process termination: 
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe" -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true "-Djna.boot.library.path=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/lib/jna/amd64" -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.noclasspath=true --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED -Dexternal.project.config=C:\Users\T14832\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2023.1\projects\campaign-admin-backend.b1b76b30\external_build_system -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Didea.IntToIntBtree.page.size=32768 -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Daether.connector.resumeDownloads=false -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=8663416678261986006 -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.language=nl -Duser.country=NL -Didea.paths.selector=IntelliJIdea2023.1 "-Didea.home.path=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3" -Didea.config.path=C:/Users/T14832/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.1 -Didea.plugins.path=C:/Users/T14832/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.1/plugins -Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/T14832/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.1/log/build-log "-Djps.fallback.jdk.home=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/jbr" -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=17.0.7 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/T14832/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.1/compile-server/campaign-admin-backend_c3241ff3/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Dtmh.instrument.annotations=true -Dtmh.generate.line.numbers=true "-Djps.kotlin.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc" -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"C:\Users\T14832\AppData\Local\Temp\kotlin-idea-12702813341039359777-is-running\" -Dide.propagate.context=false -classpath "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/plugins/java/lib/jps-javac-extension.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/lib/util.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/lib/util-8.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/lib/util_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/lib/annotations.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/lib/3rd-party-rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/lib/protobuf.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/lib/jps-model.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/lib/forms_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/lib/idea_rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/plugins/JavaEE/lib/jasper-v2-rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/lib/util.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/plugins/JavaEE/lib/javaee-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/java-guiForms-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/plugins/space/lib/space-java-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/plugins/platform-langInjection/lib/java-langInjection-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-common.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-constants-rt.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/plugins/gradle-java/lib/gradle-jps.jar;C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3/plugins/JPA/lib/jps/javaee-jpa-jps.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 61846 cd083bf2-f7fe-4805-bc19-f1d0e7163e17 C:/Users/T14832/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2023.1/compile-server
Compiler intrinsic is defined for method [jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.storeStoreFence()V], but the method is not annotated with @IntrinsicCandidate. Method will not be inlined.
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at jdk.internal.loader.BootLoader.<clinit>(java.base/BootLoader.java:62)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findNative(java.base/ClassLoader.java:2437)
    at java.lang.Thread.isAlive(java.base/Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.setDaemon(java.base/Thread.java:1402)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.<clinit>(java.base/Reference.java:313)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.base/AccessController.java:318)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.<clinit>(java.base/AccessibleObject.java:489)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jdk.internal.util.StaticProperty.getProperty(java.base/StaticProperty.java:71)
    at jdk.internal.util.StaticProperty.<clinit>(java.base/StaticProperty.java:58)
    at jdk.internal.loader.BootLoader.<clinit>(java.base/BootLoader.java:62)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findNative(java.base/ClassLoader.java:2437)
    at java.lang.Thread.isAlive(java.base/Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.setDaemon(java.base/Thread.java:1402)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.<clinit>(java.base/Reference.java:313)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.base/AccessController.java:318)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.<clinit>(java.base/AccessibleObject.java:489)
```

Comment: What is the exact Java 17 build you are using? Does it help if you install a more recent build? Does it help if you try with a more recent JDK version?

Comment: I will try that

Comment: @CrazyCoder Turns out it worked!!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, updating the jdk version worked to solve the problem.